# Rewrite recurrence relation

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I've got this assignment where I need to rewrite the following recurrence relation into the form $f(n)a_{n} = g(n)a_{n-1} + c(n)$:

$$(n-2)a_{n} = (n-6)a_{n-1} + 2(n-1)a_{n-2}$$ with $a_{0} = 2, a_{1} = 1$

I'm guessing you need to use some substitution $T_{n} = f(n)a_{n} + g(n)a_{n-1}$ to simplify this expression but I'm having difficulty finding the right substitution... I've been trying to visualize a solution, but can't manage to think of something to make this expression into the desired format.

I've been staring at this question for quite some hours now, so if anyone knows what substitution would be suitable, any help is welcome!!

Comment: If I am not wrong,I seem to have seen this same question yesterday..

Comment: @RamanujanXV I posted a similar question a couple hours ago indeed, but i mis-formulated it, hence this second attempt

Comment: @RobPratt edited the question. This one should have a solution.

Comment: @JordvanEldik 1) What is $\,a_2\,$? It is not given, and it cannot be calculated from the recurrence, but the sequence depends on it. 2) You could have edited the other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397639/solve-recurrence-relation-with-substitution) instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: @dxiv $a_2$ is not given, however I only need to rewrite this expression into the given format.

Comment: Your original recurrence relation was inconsistent: it did not match the initial conditions for $n=2$. This version eliminates this issue and is thus consistent; however, it does not produce a unique solution because $a_0,a_1$ do not determine $a_2$. There are thus an infinite number of solutions to this recurrence relation.

Comment: @Semiclassical i know, but again, that was not the question